# 8 point dft with impulse signal

Tags: signal-processing

the question is: find the dft of x(n) ={ individual digits of your roll number } - delta (n) using DIT FFT

I do not understand this question. what do I do with the impulse signal here? if it was just x(n) then it can easily be solved but how do I subtract the impulse signal from x(n)
[here is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuqqB.png)

Comment: Please type up your question to make it self contained.

Comment: I did.....................